# Maximizing a cost-function while minimizing another, under constraints.

Tags: optimization, problem-solving, lagrange-multiplier, adjoint-operators, inverse-problems

**The problem**

Find the solution for $argmin_{(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{q},\mathbf{f})} \,\mathcal{J}$, and $argmax_{(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{q},\mathbf{f})} \,\mathcal{K}$, with,

$\mathcal{J}=||\mathbf{I} \, \mathbf{f}-\mathbf{y}||^2$

$\mathcal{K}=||\mathbf{q}||^2$.

$\mathbf{u}$ is linked to $\mathbf{f},\mathbf{q}$ by the non-linear equation $\mathcal{N}$,

$\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f},\mathbf{q},\mathbf{u})=0$.

$\mathbf{f},\mathbf{q},\mathbf{u}$ are all unknown discrete complex vectors of size $n$.

$\mathbf{y}$ is a known complex vector of size $m$, with $m<n$. $\mathbf{I}$ is a known matrix of size $n\times m$.

$\mathcal{N}$ is differentiable, $\partial_\mathbf{x} \, \mathcal{N}$ is known for all variables $\mathbf{x}$

**Some context**

This is actually the inverse problem of what I usually solve, where $\mathbf{u}$ is known but not $\mathbf{y}$. If $\mathbf{u}$ is known, $\mathbf{f}$ can easily be found using non-linear optimization and the adjoint equation to $\mathcal{N}$.

I feel like it should be solvable using some weird successive non-linear iterative approach. Reasonable guess value can be provided for both $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{u}$. I have tried to reduce the problem to its essence, I can give more detail if necessary.

***Would it be reasonable to optimize the following Lagrange function?***

$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{u}^{\dagger},\mathbf{u},\mathbf{q},\mathbf{f})= \, + \,\mathcal{J}(\mathbf{f}) \, - \,\mathcal{K}(\mathbf{q}) \,\,\,- \,< \mathbf{u}^{\dagger},\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{q},\mathbf{f})>$

Note the different signs before $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{J}$.